# Kill a Process in the Kernel

Tags: android, linux, exception, linux-kernel, kernel

I'm working on a research project, which tries to find some unusual/malicious states/inputs in the kernel, and stops the kernel thread from further execution immediately.

For example, a process issues a system call with malicious arguments, and its kernel thread executes it.
In the middle of function `Foo()`, we use a probe to find that the argument is malicious. And the function has no return value (`void`). Now we need to kill this process and its corresponding kernel part, and free the resources it uses (locks, etc.).

How to implement it in Linux/Android kernel?

My current idea is to suspend (call `schedule()` to make it sleep) the thread forever, and try to kill the process. However, the "kill" signal can only take effect when the process is in user-space, which is too late.

Comment: At which level(user or kernel) function `Foo()` works? In user space sending signal is the only way to stop *other* thread. In the kernel space situation with stopping other thread is the same. But if you execute `Foo()` function from the thread itself, you may send signal to that thread and return from syscall - signal processing will be done after that.

Comment: Foo() is in kernel space (the process's kernel thread).  I want it to be killed in the kernel space, not when it goes back to user-space.

Comment: `I want it to be killed in the kernel space, not when it goes back to user-space.` - killing the process with SIGKILL is transparent for user space, it is not possible to register handler for that signal or catch it by other means. Another way for stop process is `do_exit(ret_code)`, this is effectively same as `exit()` system call.

Comment: If exit(), will resources such as locks be released?

Comment: No, kernel locks should be released manually, they have no automatic unlocking mechanism. So you need to call `do_exit()` at the safe point, when syscall processing doesn't hold kernel-only resources. From the other side, all user resources, like opened files, are gracefully closed on exit.

Comment: Doesn't seccomp already do that ? https://lwn.net/Articles/656307/